# Does stun prevent sustain actions?

Tags: black-crusade

The stunned action, that can be inflicted with stun action or knockdown action, states that it prevents the execution of actions. Does this include all actions, including free actions to sustain powers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 257 in the CRB it states

> In addition, Stunned characters cannot take Actions or Reactions such as Evasion.

Free actions require you be able to spend actions, so if you are temporarily stunned you lose the ability to take free actions and therefore lose the ability to sustain those powers. For this reason, stun can be very powerful against combat psykers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, these were my thoughta but wanted confirmation.